# Site icon on WP8 homescreen

Tags: windows-phone-8

iOS, Android, and even BlackBerry allow you to specify an icon that is displayed when you bookmark a page to the device's homescreen. And now Windows 8 allows you to specify an icon that appears when a page is pinned to the start screen as follows:

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="logo144.png"/>
```

However, this doesn't seem to apply to Windows **Phone** 8. Is that correct? Is there some other way in WP8 to specify an icon to be used (instead of a screenshot) that my Google ninja skills have failed uncover?

Comment: Have you found an solution, or is the answer of Pete the best option at the moment. Thanks in Advance for sharing.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows Phone 8.1 you can specify the image, title, colour of tile and even push notifications using meta tags. For the name use

```
<meta name="application-name" content="NAME HERE" />
```

For the tile colour

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content=" #009900" />
```

Logos for all four tile sizes

```
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="smalltile.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="mediumtile.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="widetile.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="largetile.png" />
```

Polling is more complex, so all the details are [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/05/21/support-a-live-tile-for-your-website-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1.aspx)

Comment: Thx a lot, that really helped. Oh, and it´ also working on WP10!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Windows Phone will only pin a screenshot of the current browser window when you click "pin to start".  There are ways around this and I have an example **with code** that displays a custom image and asks users to pin while the image is displayed.  With all work-arounds, this has issues since the user has to trigger the image *and then* use the browser's pinning function.  But it is working pretty well.

Link to the example code
http://cdpn.io/jlEur

If I were you, before making this code go live, I would at least use a cookie to see if you have prompted the user with the "pin" already.

Answer (score 1):

According to the website [Webmonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/11/internet-explorer-10-for-mobile-html5/):

"While IE 10 for Windows Phone 8 is very close to feature parity with the desktop/tablet release, there are a few things web developers need to be aware of. Here’s Microsoft’s full list of things IE 10 can do on the desktop but ***not*** on phones:

Windows 8 integration features: Link previews, **pinned site icons** & notifications and support for connecting sites to apps"