# Is there a way to get a mobile webapp icon to apear as the tile when pinning to start screen on a Windows Phone?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web-applications, windows-phone, meta-tags

I'm currently using a code snippet from the "HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate" project, but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know of a workaround for this?

`<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/icon-144.png">`

`<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#222222">`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly those meta tags works only for sites pinned with Internet Explorer in Windows 8 (Here is a good reference for Windows 8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255024(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can't do the same for Windows Phone right now, see a similair question here which answer is still correct: [Site icon on WP8 homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943931/site-icon-on-wp8-homescreen).