# how to make icon of a website to put on mobile

Tags: java, php, html

I have a fully responsive website so there is no need to have mobile app for the website. However most of my visitors will be access the site from mobile phones and their  IT knowledge is limited. I want to create an icon which the visitors can download and put as icon short cut on phone. I know there is a way to create short cut icon on smartphone like bookmark , but most of my users won't know how to do it and  it will be difficult for them to follow instructions. Can anyone help? 
Thanks

Comment: You can't "download an icon" from a web URL, you either have to package it as an app on an app store, tell people to bookmark it as you mentioned, or find a way to make sure people have easy access to the website when they need it, e.g. using QR codes

Comment: @raphv Actually, Apple officially supports web apps that come off the internet. They essentially run in Safari, but the UI is striped leaving just the HTML. Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

Comment: True, but in terms of user experience, this doesn't remove the bookmarking step, which is why I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 4):

Across **all mobile operating systems**, these are the best solutions to my knowledge.

For **Apple iOS**, according to their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), you can add this **HTML tag** to your page to specify an icon for the user's home screen, if they add it:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/path/to/icon.png">
```

You can also set a specific sized icon for screens with a higher resolution:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/path/to/touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/path/to/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/path/to/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

Those same tags should work on **Android**, though you may have to create a **json manifest** to set an icon for sure. [See here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen).

For **Windows Phone**, the solution isn't as clear, though this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943931/site-icon-on-wp8-homescreen) on Stack Overflow might be a good start, at least partly.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Wish you the best.

Comment: Thank you  very much to all of you  for taking time to answer my question. As William Casey suggest, the user still need to visit the home page then click bookmark and save icon to phone home page. The problem is most of my users are not technical . The solution I am looking for  is for users go to main page at once and from there download the icon/ apps and open the web page later on through icon/ app .